# Momentum conservation in fission

Tags: momentum, atomic-physics

In a fission reaction a neutron collides with another atom. In this process, is the momentum conserved? Some masses turn into energy, so can't it happen that the momentum is not conserved?

Comment: conservation of energy and momentum are absolute laws , i.e. equivalent to axioms, for physics theories, and there have not been any falsifications of the theories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Momentum conservation is a consequence of a fundamental symmetry called [translational symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translational_symmetry). As such it is a fundamental property of our universe and momentum is always conserved. Even when massive particles disappear completely by converting into photons the momentum is still conserved because even though they are massless photons carry momentum.

Comment: Is it the momentum given by: $E=pc$? Then it's really confusing.

Comment: $p=h/\lambda$ That works for photons and de Broglie waves. For light $E=hc/\lambda$ so your equation is also correct.